# I can't seem to run my function from an extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to develop an extension but I can't seem to get my js function to run.

Here are the elements:-

1.Manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "KS Scrapper",
    "description":"Simple Scrapper",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "icons":{"128":"images/ks_logo_128.png"},
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "images/ks_logo_19.png",
        "default_popup" : "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts" : [
            {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js" : ["popup.js"],
            "css" : ["c.css"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "css/style.css"
    ],
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    }
}
```

2.popup.js

```
var a = chrome.extension.getURL("c.css");
$('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + a + '" >').appendTo("head");

chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").hover(function(){

            //if get onhover id
            alert("NOW GET ON HOVER ID NAME:--"+" "+this.id);

            //if get onhover class
            console.log("NOW GET ON HOVER CLASS NAME:--"+" "+$(this).attr('class'));


        });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong would really be appreciated.
I can't get an alert or an output in the console. Help would be greatly appreciated. Also if someone would help me to solve the following error I get when running the extension I would be really grateful.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Review the [extension's architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). Content scripts are limited in the APIs they can access (for example, they cannot use `chrome.tabs`). You cannot use jQuery's `$` unless you load jQuery with your extension.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.....I've added made the changes "js" : ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "popup.js"], in the content script in the manifest.json but I'm still getting the $ not defined error....is it possible to share a snippet of what I should do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `npm i jquery` then within the `node_modules/jquery/dist` directory copy `jquery.min.js` and move it to your extension's main content script folder.

You could then link to it inside your `popup.html` file in the line above your `popup.js` file.

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It is also worth noting that usually the `popup.js` file is imported into `popup.html` through a `<script>` tag. You don't need to add `popup.js` to the content_scripts section of your manifest.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info did what you said and it worked. Actually was kinda playing around with the extension and forgot to change the name of the popup.js to content.js.